# reinterpret_cast - An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be converted to its own type

Tags: c++, c++11

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be converted to its own type. The resulting value is the same as the value of expression. (since C++11)

Why should I be interested in converting something to its own type? This reads to me as I would want to convert int to int.

Please correct me.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr)` -> `ptr` can be converted to it's own type `char*`. The cast's own type is `char*`

Comment: It certainly would be weird if converting int to int were not permitted!

Comment: @RaymondChen But why would you want to convert int to int. It is already int.

Comment: The language specification concerns itself with what is *permitted*, not with the reason why you be interested in it. And the null conversion is something you really want to be permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because maybe you don't know if it is "its own type". Maybe you're in a template function, where you're calling some function whose return value you require to be `reinterpret_cast`able to a template parameter `T`. So it's OK for that function to return a value of type `T`.

For a more useful example, let's say you're given some object of a type `T`. And you call a function on that that's supposed to return a pointer of some sort. And you want to cast this pointer to a `char*` and do some low-level messing around, perhaps to pass it to `memcpy` or something.

Well, what happens if the function returned a `char*`? That is, it returned a string. You need `reinterpret_cast<char*>` to still work.

Comment: Oh, that's what it means! Thank you.

Comment: And in this case using static_cast would not make sense because with templates we static_cast would not know the type?